# password_hash returns NULL

Tags: php, password-hash

How come the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) states that `password_hash` can return either a string or value false, but the following line of code returns NULL?

```
$password = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_BDCRYPT, array( 'cost' => 10 ));
```

Comment: Did you have a *question*?

Comment: *Seems like they had to take off somewhere Sam* - @JayBlanchard Maybe we'll all get a coffee and danish when they come back ;-)

Comment: *I could eat, Ralph* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Lunchtime's only... 3-4 hours away Sam - @JayBlanchard can't wait to hear that whistle blow.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have rephrased it in the form of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the fact that it is not documented, the function does return NULL when one provides an incorrect value for algorithm.

Currently supported constants are:

- `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`
- `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`

And a typo in this case (`PASSWORD_BDCRYPT` rather than `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`) results in the value of NULL being passed, that in turn causes the same value as the return.

---

Edit: Any other string that has not been defined before would also evaluate as NULL.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried using any other string, say ABCDEFG_HIJK for example or XXXXXXXXXXX?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Anything that hasn't been previously defined is evaluated as `NULL` in php, thus there is no reason to try different undefined strings, the result will be the same.

Comment: That would be something that should be added in your Q&A then, should comments get deleted and for future visitors to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, incorrect parameter results in NULL being returned. Just to be complete: note that this goes not for just incorrect algorithm number, but also for providing incorrect $options parameter - e.g. calling:

```
password_hash('something', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, 10);
```

will also return NULL with no other error.