# php - password_hash returns false

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I'm writing a `Password` class and I'm using `password_hash` with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` to create the hash.

The documentation says that `password_hash` could also return `false` if the hashing fails. In that case I'm throwing an exception and I would like to test this case carefully.

Do you have an example of a string `$password` such that `password_hash($spassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) === false`?

This has nothing to do with `password_verify` returning `false` when it doesn't match the hash.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I guess that in that case is `password_verify` that returns `false`, not `password_hash`

Comment: oh sorry. you're right, my bad. however, the next result google gave ne contains the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226295/password-hash-returns-null - it's not about an invalid pasword but an invalid algorithm

Comment: I assume that the only time `password_hash` could fail would be if your server is not configured properly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I would expect more an Error or an Exception in such a case, but you may be right. Do you have in mind an easy way to test it?

Comment: Little do some people know that, `password_hash()` won't throw any errors (or MySQL for that matter, if you are using MySQL or other similar RDBMS and will fail silently) should the column's length be too short; that's IF that is what the question is about and is related to it. All you can do is to handle on failure. Using exceptions or a try/catch won't work if that's the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, but the question is not about that. Just looking for a value that causes the return value of `password_hash` to be false

Comment: I don't think there is a guaranteed way to get password_hash to return false. By definition it's for failures the Zend developers didn't think would happen. I don't really see why you would need to make PHP return false for a unit test anyway, you can just call your code for handling a false response directly.

Comment: @Chris I just want to test the case where `password_hash` returns `false`. It is a possible case and no errors or exceptions are thrown, so it seems to ma sensible to test it

Comment: Checking that you are correctly comparing a variable to `false` seems like an overly trivial unit test. If you really want to do it though the neatest thing I can suggest is wrapping `password_hash` in a function that can be made to return false during a test.

Comment: @Chris I'm using `password_hash` inside another function, but there is code that is executed only if `password_hash` returns false, and that is the code I would like to test

Answer (score 1):

Even it's quite old, but I had the very same question and dove a little depeer into. So I share my sparse results here:

- [the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226295/password-hash-returns-null) has actually a different topic: "when does `password_hash` return `null`". That's the case when it can't handle stuff in the `$options`-parameter (like (`"cost" => -1`) or whatever. But it's about `null`, not `false`.
- I tried various exotic strings (raw bytes, very very long strings, null-bytes etc.= but never got a `false` neither with for `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, not with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` in 5.5, 5.6 and 7.4.
- Compability-Libs for older PHP-Versions (without native `password-hash`-function) may return false:

  - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/compatibility_functions.html#password_hash
  - https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/issues/90
  - https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/issues/17
- Looking at the source code of PHP:

  - [In older versions (like 5.5.3)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d005ed9681d6797012570c4e32abb3abcdf3b72a/ext/standard/password.c#L308), there are various `false`-cases that are hard to recapitulate (like, when [this](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d005ed9681d6797012570c4e32abb3abcdf3b72a/ext/standard/crypt_sha512.c#L661) happens). [But even the PHP developers themselves do not test for those](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.5.3/ext/standard/tests/password), so I get the impression they are only happening in very specialized circumstances, when the underlying c-libraries for encryption fail and are not triggerable with a special password.
  - Even in 7.3 [I can find some `false`-cases](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cb265a0addf15c5cf0c029f167a9de030150cf15/ext/standard/password.c#L492), when [deep down in the crypt-libraries null pointers occur for example](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cb265a0addf15c5cf0c029f167a9de030150cf15/ext/standard/crypt.c#L123). I am not enough of a c-programmer to tell if this is likely or even possible. But there are [still no tests](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.3.18/ext/standard/tests/password) for `false`.
  - In current master (7.4) there [is no `false`-case left](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/901417f0ae02afc8bef904818edaf2b2db8f6b58/ext/standard/password.c#L655), although still stated in the docs. `password_hash` throws exceptions in every case of error as you would expect.

**Conclusion**: 
I think it's best to catch the `false` case (and thus the `null`-case as well, although it can not happen if no `$options` provided), may it be as unlikely as it is. This is maybe the most crucial part of your application! Especially when using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, since it may change over time and therefore it's behavior, or older versions of PHP are allowed for your application. I would throw a fatal error here or even `die` out, since as far I can see, the `false`-case can only happen due to serious misconfiguration of the server. Therefore it can not be tested in unit-tests.

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (!$hash) {

  trigger_error("Fatal error when encrypting the password", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```